# 'Security' tab missing from Chrome developers tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I opened the Chrome today after a few days and see that the 'Security' tab is missing from the developers tools tabs. Is this an issue or a new update? Any fixes?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Either you accidentally closed the Security tab or an extension did it for you. Click the kebab menu (between the gear icon and X in your screenshot), choose More tools, and re-select the Security.

Comment: Ya I did actually close the security tab accidently and forgot about it. Thanks.

Comment: I pressed the X accidentally in Chrome whilst in a practical exam with very tight timescales, and couldn't work out how to open it again. My solution was to open Chromium instead and then load the web-page so I could view the security info I needed for the answer. Glad it's simple, but I couldn't find it under pressure. :)

Answer (score 3):

1.Open developer tools.
2.click on gear icon.
3. Scroll down,click on restore defaults and reload

You will able to see all tabs in developer tools